# How to test code for Memory Leaks?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Help to understand whether there is a memory leak or not.
**Fragment**

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
//some code
private OnNewsFeedsContentClickListener onNewsFeedsContentClickListener = new OnNewsFeedsContentClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(String sYoutubeId, ContentType type)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

}

**Adapter**

```
public class HowToAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static final String TAG = "HowToAdapter";
private List<ContentSkill> mContentList = null;
private Context mContext = null;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader = null;
private OnNewsFeedsContentClickListener mOnNewsFeedsContentClickListener = null;

public HowToAdapter(Context context, List<ContentSkill> contetnList, OnNewsFeedsContentClickListener onNewsFeedsContentClickListener)
{
    mContext = context;
    mContentList = contetnList;
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext, ImageType.HOW_TO);
    mOnNewsFeedsContentClickListener = onNewsFeedsContentClickListener;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    HowToView view = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        view = new HowToView(mContext);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (HowToView) convertView;
    }
    ContentSkill content = getItem(position);
    if (content != null)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final String url = Utils.getYouTubeUrlImageFromUrl(content.getUrl());
        final String youtubeId = Utils.getYoutubeIdFromUrl(content.getUrl());
        mImageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.pIvThumb);
        holder.pIvThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mOnNewsFeedsContentClickListener.onClick(youtubeId, ContentType.VIDEO);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

**Questions**:

1. The adapter variable **final String youtubeId** will always be created,
   but not killed? That is, each time getView() will be created but
   the old **youtubeId** not clear from memory?
2. Each time call getView() OnClickListener will also be created, and the old
   will be cleaned out of memory?

I think that the variables will be re-created each time and catch-up with the old memory.

Comment: In both cases, when no live treads can access the the variables, then their resource can be reclaimed and reused again. I think the both answer is `Yes`.

Comment: Yes I said it is better to declare a variable of a class of ViewHolder and transmit it to the OncliclListener. But the question is whether a memory leak in the code set out above or not.